# 4-vector Minkowski Force

Tags: special-relativity, forces, reference-frames, inertial-frames

The whole of special relativity was set up with the principle that all inertial frames are equivalent and nature's laws appear the same in every reference frame. However, while defining quantities like the Minkowski Force 4-vector $K$, under Lorentz transformation, our new force 4-vector is $K'$ and $K$ is not equal to $K'$ and thus, even 4-vector Minkowski force transform under Lorentz transformations just like 4-momenta, making some frame of reference unique. The whole notion of all inertial frames being valid goes down the drain with this. How is this possible?

Comment: *even forces transform under Lorentz transformations just like 4-momenta, making some frame of reference unique* - could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I'm talking about the 4-vector Minkowski Force $K= dP^\mu/d\tau$. After a lorrentz transformation, we'll be having $K'$ which is not equal to $K$

Comment: *even forces transform under Lorentz transformations just like 4-momenta, making some frame of reference unique* This is a *non-sequitur*.

Comment: Updated my question to clarify this part.

Comment: Given a vector $\mathbf K$, its description [i.e., in terms of components] depends on the choice of coordinate axes, centered at the tail of the vector, one grid rotated with respect to the other. This notion applies analogously to 4-vectors in special relativity.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with what you consider to be the meaning of equivalent. You seem to mistake it with identical coordinates in any coordinate frame. This can't make sense, I will try to explain that starting from a classical mechancis example.

If I'm on a boat and I watch a person $B$ jump from a cliff, me and the person next to me will, for example, have different ideas on where the person $B$ is and in what direction $B$ is falling. My neighbor may claim that $B$ is 1 meter more to the right than I think. It is quite clear that there is no distinguished way of talking about the position, it's just a matter of the origin of your coordinate frame.

Fine, you might say, but that's position, but force is more fundamental, and wherever my neighbor sits on the boat, and even if my neighbor were driving by in a jet ski at constant speed, the force would always be the same. But that no longer holds true when my neighbor is riding their jet ski in a handstand. Now their view is upside-down and the person seems to be falling up. Here, there is no inherent reason to consider the direction of gravity to be "down". It can go in any direction, and the neighbor in a rotated coordinate frame observes exactly the same physics as I do.

It is mathematically not too far from the truth that the Lorentz transformation is a sort of rotation in space-time. If you change to a moving frame, space and time get "rotated" by the hyperbolic functions $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ that play analogous roles as they do in regular rotation described by trigonometric functions $\sin$ and $\cos$. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_mapping). If we accept time as being intertwined with space, it is quite natural to accept that in the consequence, an observer with a properly "rotated" space-time will witness the same physics, just described by different coordinates.

Comment: So in layman's term, as lorrentz transformation is like a rotation of space time, this transformation will have 'centrifugal' effects for the observer measuring in that frame, which are like pseudoforces?

Comment: The opposite, actually. Maybe my answer was unclear on that, I made a correction when it comes to the other observer standing upside down. This isn't a rotation at constant speed. It is a once-and-for-all rotation of the coordinate system. It's likes swapping left and right: there is no coriolis force associated with that, but the flipped coordinate changes sign.

Comment: There is no new force term appearing, it is just that, for example, a force that has been acting solely in the "time" direction before now also has a component acting in the space direction. It's like when you have a force acting in $x$ direction in a coordinate frame in classical mechanics. If you choose to use a tilted coordinate frame instead, the force may gain a component acting in the $y$ direction of the new coordinate system, but it's still the same force. Like the tangential and normal forces of a weight on an inclined plane versus the forces acting in $x$ and $y$ direction.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! :D